# Facebook Instant Game JS Cookie Chrome Error

Tags: javascript, facebook, cookies, facebook-instant-games

we have a game made on JavaScript and HTML.
All works fine on Safari, Firefox, and on mobile App.
The issue is that on Chrome, on the game page Cookies are NOT set.

We usually do this:

```
function setCookie(name, value, days) {
    var expires = "";
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        expires = "; expires=" + date.toUTCString();
    }
    document.cookie = name + "=" + (value || "") + expires + "; path=/";
}
```

The function works fine on all the browsers except for Chrome.
We even try with a library called js-cookie but it simply doesn't set the values.

Are we missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was the domain.
Facebook use:

```
.facebook.com
```

But the app on Instant Games has another domain like:

```
apps-*.apps.fbsbx.com
```

The cookie is not set because this:

```
https://blog.heroku.com/chrome-changes-samesite-cookie
```

I just chane the cookie to add:

```
{ sameSite: "None", secure: true, expires: 7 }
```

And that works fine.

Answer (score 0):

How are you calling your function? The following function can safely create a cookie in Chrome.

```js
const DAY_IN_MILLIS = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;

const createCookie = (name, value = '', days = 0) => {
  const cookie = { [name]: value };
  if (days) {
    const date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * DAY_IN_MILLIS));
    cookie.expires = date.toUTCString();
  }
  return Object.entries({ ...cookie, path: '/' })
    .map(pair => pair.join('=')).join('; ');
};

const setCookie = (name, value, days) => {
  document.cookie = createCookie(name, value, days);
};

console.log(createCookie('username', 'John Doe'));
console.log(createCookie('username', 'John Doe', 1));
```

Comment: Isn't working to
I just call 

$.ready = function () {
    setCookie("survey", "0");
}

But it simply doesn't work on facebook

Comment: It prints username=John Doe; expires=Thu, 11 Mar 2021 19:32:06 GMT; path=/
13:32:06.556 but the cookie is not on the console

Comment: @Ulises my example just “creates” and prints the cookie. You need to set it. The snippet just shows the output that goes into the cookie.